# How to send sms message on specific area using Longitude and Latitude

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm, mpu6050, tinygps

Good day everyone! what code should i used for sending sms message depends on the area. the things that i used in my protoype i have MPU6050 accelometer, SIM800C GSM MODULE, NEO6MV2 GPS MODULE. So the flow is if the Accelometer triggred the GSM module will get the GPS location only if the area is on the target location 1 so it will only send to the recepient 1. But if its triggred in another location, Targetlocation2 it will only send on receipient 2.
My question is how to used the longitude and latitude data to get the exact data of what my gps module gets? so that i can use that data to send sms message on specific place or area thank a lot
also i used TINYGPS.H LIBRARY thank you!

Comment: You get location information from GPS, and you have some target locations stored. You check, which of the targets is closest and send an SMS to the corresponding phone. And what exactly is your problem in detail?  If you ask "How to do it?" rather show what you tried and why you are not satisfied with the result. And split the task into a couple of smaller ones :)

Comment: why are you asking again? ... https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/72626/how-to-send-sms-message-depends-on-the-gps-locatiom

Comment: Thank you DataFiddler i'm just asking for a format code use to set longitude and latitude, Is it float distance_between (float Lat1, float Lon1, float Lat2, float Lon2)? and how to set this for if statement? to send the sms if my location area is on the target Lat1 Lon1 thank you

Comment: sorry jsotola im just despirate sorry for my bad  english